# QMake and a .pro file

Tags: qmake

I've downloaded a package and am trying to build/install it. The project's wiki page has a command that looks like

```
qmake VAR=/path/to/something/ project.pro
```

It says that this command should tell `qmake` to generate a make file. Instead, I'm getting

```
qmake: Nothing to be done for `project.pro'.
```

Why is `qmake` not generating the make file like it's supposed to?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the project in questions or the contents of the project (.pro) file, it is difficult to diagnose. One possibility is that qmake was already run, or that the files it is to generate are included with your download. In these circumstances, there really is nothing to be done for said project.

As a side note, may I recommend downloading "Qt Creator" and opening the project file in there? Qt Creator tends to make Qt development and project building a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I just answered my own question... apparently there is more than one `qmake`. On my system, we're using a `qmake: distributed parallel make, scheduling by Grid Engine.` I found `/etc/alternatives/qmake` which is the QT qmake...